# How to rotate an html element with jquery on scroll percentage?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, rotation

I want to rotate a div on scroll.
When I scrolled down 25% of the page I want the element to be rotated 90*, when I scrolled 50% of the page I want it to be rotated 180*, and so on.
Someone advised me to use jQueryRotat.js, I filled it all in on JSfiddle, but I can't get it working. You can check what I already have here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMQCy/6/)

This is what I got so far

HTML:

```
<div class="site_wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
    </div>
</div
```

CSS:

```
.site_wrapper{
    max-width:200px;
    height:10000px;
    margin:auto;
    background:#555;
}

.logo{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin-left:-75px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:url(http://www.gielesdesign.nl/imgs/textures/texture-1.jpg);
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    left:50%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Might want to include the javascript in the question too for completeness.

Comment: *"Uncaught ReferenceError: windowHeight is not defined "* the rotate plugin isn't even being executed in your fiddle

Comment: in your fiddle you havent attached any function to the onscroll event

Answer (score 4):

You do not have `windowHeight` defined also you do not have a `onscroll` event set

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var bodyHeight = $("body").height()-$(window).height();
   window.onscroll = function() {

      //Determine the amount to rotate by.
      var deg = -window.scrollY*(360/bodyHeight);

      $(".logo").css({
        "transform": "rotate("+deg+"deg)",
      });

   };
});
```

and as suggested by Blazemonger, subtract the windows height from body height to get a full rotation when at the end of the page.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMQCy/14/)

Comment: You should subtract `$(window).height()` from `bodyHeight` to get a full rotation. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/NMQCy/13/

Comment: Also, the OP was using [jQueryRotate.js](https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) instead of straight CSS3, probably because the plugin supports older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I make [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NMQCy/9/) for your (with optional caching)

use

```
$(window).scroll(function(){});
```

Comment: Okay, eehm. I want it to smoothly rotate, when you scroll, it rotates, when you scroll back, it rotates the other way around..

Answer (score 0):

You need to both attach your function to `$(document).scroll()` and I also think you want to use `$(document)` instead of `$(window)` to get page height. Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2h4C/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few issues. First, you need to trigger it whenever the window is scrolled by using the `$(window).on('scroll')` event.

Second, `windowheight` isn't a variable in your code. I replaced it with `$(window).height()`, but then decided it wasn't actually necessary and remove that test entirely.

Finally, I updated your `.rotate` parameters. The intial `angle` should be the element's current angle, obtained by calling the `.getRotateAngle()` method. The terminal angle (between zero and 180 degrees) can be computed by dividing the current `scrollTop` by the entire document's height, less the window height -- then multiply that by `-180`.

The end result is a logo that smoothly rotates as you scroll up and down the page.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
        $(".logo").rotate({
            duration: 1, /* why wait? No easing needed now, either */
            angle: $('.logo').getRotateAngle(),
            animateTo: -180 * $(window).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height())
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/nqm2w/